# Rewriting function into class

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a function for changing password of a user, now I'd like to rewrite it to a class view, it gives me an error:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

Function:

```
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Class View so far

```
class ChangePasswordView(FormValidMessageMixin, FormInvalidMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'accounts/change_password.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')

    def get_form_valid_message(self):
        return 'Your password was successfully updated!'

    def get_form_invalid_message(self):
        return 'Please correct the error below.'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.author = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
path('change-password/', ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name='change-password'),
```

Comment: Which class are you getting the error on?

Comment: What does the `urls.py` entry look like for `ChangePasswordView`? It sounds like it has `user` in it and it shouldn't.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I don't see an error related to any class (no message in Debug mode).

Comment: @schillingt updated!

Comment: can you share the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your form requires an argument `user`. So you need to override `get_form_kwargs()` method in your form view to pass it, like this:

```
class ChangePasswordView(FormValidMessageMixin, FormInvalidMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    # rest of the code
    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
       form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
       form_kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
       return form_kwargs
```

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you. I had to change one thing as well. When I implemented your result I got other error, that `PasswordChangeForm` doesn't have `instance`. After removing it, everything have worked :)